# Google FusedLocationApi API there are so many time onConnectionSuspended called and i am unable to get GPS location

Tags: android, google-maps, service, gps

I have used **GoogleApiClient** for getting GPS location. i have create one service and every 10 seconds getting data from GPS but the problem is there are so many times **onConnectionSuspended()**  called and i am not geeting any GPS data.
following is my service code that i am getting GPS location

```
 <service
            android:name="com.GPSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":ServiceProcess"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Service code

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected boolean requestingLocationUpdate = true;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 5; // 5 meters

    private static final String LOCATION = "Location Not Available";

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String mLastUpdateTime;
    Intent intents;
    RequestParams requestParams = null;

    private static final String TAG = "GPSService";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        helper.insertServiceLog("oncreate");
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("GPSService", "onCreate");
//

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
       }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("MyReceiver", "onTaskRemoved called  Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        super.onStart(intent, startid);

        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("GPSService", "onStart");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && requestingLocationUpdate) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY; 
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //String imei = "2";

        mLastLocation = loc;
          double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        if (requestingLocationUpdate) {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
            startLocationUpdates();
             Toast.makeText(this, "Started the location update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    Log.d("GPSService", "onConnectionSuspended called");
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     */

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.i("MyReceiver", "onTaskRemoved called  Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```

can somebody please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you're running the service in a different process? I think it might be related that. Try changing the declaration of the service to

```
<service
    android:name="com.GPSService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```